# How to model a JSON with pair meta/result

Tags: json, oop, modeling

I'm implementing multiple REST client wrappers (Java, C#, Objective-C and Python) for a REST service for which I don't have the source code access. In all of them I'm having problems with the modeling, so of course you can assume my flaw is in the OOP, not on the language syntax or smth. I wondered maybe someone could help me fixing this flaw or finding out if the REST service is the problem, and hopefully this topic can help others improving their OOP modeling.

The WebService will always return a JSON with the following structure:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200,
        "message": "OK"
    },
    "result": [
        {
             ...
        },
        {
             ...
        },
        ...
        ]
    }
}
```

The problem is: "meta" will always have the same model and the "result" will always be a list of objects, but these objects change depending on the Endpoint we access. So I have multiple classes, each for one Endpoint, and result will always end up being a list of one of these classes. So I thought of multiple ways of solving it, none of them I really liked. Any other alternatives besides the following methods? Thanks.

## Method 1

Meta class with code and message fields, ServiceResponse class with meta field and result field as JSONData

Each specific class having a constructor with JSONData as parameter, which is parsed on create.

### Problem

JSONData is not encapsulated as it has to be handled all the time, and the performance is bad because of parsing the same JSONData multiple times, since ServiceResponse doesn't hold the parsed objects.

## Method 2

Making one ModelResponse for each different class I have. E.g. ProductsResponse with meta and a list of products, VenuesResponse with a meta and a list of products, etc.

### Problem

Poor code reuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after explaining the question here and thinking for a couple of hours about it, making PoCs and so on I came to what I think is a good efficient modeling.

I basically chose Method 2 and fixed the "poor code reuse" problem, by doing the following. I'll use a pseudo-language to be as general as possible so that anyone with knowledge in Object-Oriented Programming will understand:

```
abstract class ServiceResponse:
    int code
    string message
    JsonReader _reader
    void parseMeta():
        _reader.beginObject()
        ...
        _reader.endObject()

    abstract void parseResult() // will be implemented by child classes

    public ServiceResponse(JsonReader reader):
        _reader = reader
        _reader.beginObject()
        ...
             parseMeta()
        ...
             parseResult()
        ...
        _reader.endObject()
```

Then for each kind of response I create a class that inherits from ServiceResponse, such as:

```
class ProductsResponse extends ServiceResponse:
     List<Products> products
     public ProductsResponse(JsonReader reader):
         parent(reader)
     override void parseResult():
         _reader.beginArray();
         ...
         _reader.endArray();
```

And then I have a ServiceEndpoints class which has one method for each endpoint. Through the WS documentation I know which endpoint will return which type of response, so I can instantiate the right class (ProductsResponse, VenuesResponse, etc) and return the right type of list.